# Error: invalid_request, error_description: Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing when trying to get an access token (Buffer API)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to recieve an access token from the following URL:

https://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json

The following code is my POST request, I seem to have everything included according to the Buffer API documentation and the OAuth 2 rules:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    },
    data: {
        client_id: "{MY_CLIENT_ID}",
        client_secret: "{MY_CLIENT_SECRET}",
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost/testexample",
        code: "{MY_AUTH_CODE}",
        grant_type: "authorization_code"
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) { 
        console.log(response);
    },
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

When I execute the code, I recieve the error:
net::ERR_ABORTED, and the URL returns:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem within my Laravel code, It is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

> Also note that the code parameter must not be url encoded - ie. it
>   should be formatted like 1/mWot20jTwojsd00jFlaaR45 and not
>   1%2FmWot20jTwojsd00jFlaaR45.

but in the headers you set the content to:

```
'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
```

I'm not sure if that makes a difference if you are not encoding the "code" but could be worth trying without that content-type.

> EDIT -  I also tried this and makes no difference. So:

I would suggest removing the "jsonp" datatype as it's a POST not a GET.  Possibly that could add something to the request which the token endpoint doesn't like. Alternatively try using an HTTP tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to POST the data.

If you need to make a cross origin call, maybe you can use CORS instead?

If you use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (or any other type of HTTP traffic inspection tool) you should be able to see the actual request sent and the problem will then likely be more transparent.

Should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work. The Buffer API documentation said the following:

But be sure to set the HTTP Content-Type header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for your requests if you are writing your own client.

Comment: strange - your post looks right - there aren't non-ascii characters within the client id or secret which *do* require encoding are there? Are you able to show the raw form data you are submitting? (obviously obfuscate your client id and secret!)

Comment: This is the data (I changed the characters in the client_id and secret):

client_id: "4g7c61a839bt2f9f6x846d72",
client_secret: "gefrh1a1654bde533660282511xf65eq",
redirect_uri: "http: //localhost/authreaction",
code: 1/056ca547b25734385f08c2249ea9b67r,
grant_type: "authorization_code"

Comment: Have you tried without the "jsonp" datatype? I didn't know you could use that on a post.